# PHP: Share session on some subdomains, but not all

Tags: php, subdomain, session-cookies

I have 1 domain and 2 subdomains, lets say:

```
domain.com
a.domain.com
b.domain.com
```

I would like for *domain.com* and the *a.domain.com* to share their PHP session, but for *b.domain.com* to have a session of its own.

How can I approach this with PHP's ini_set('session.cookie_domain', ...) ?

All I can find online is

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.domain.com')
```

But this applies to all subdomains...

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who needs it, it turns out the solution for this was naming my sessions. I stored the name of the session on my .env file:

```
session_name($_ENV['SESSION_NAME']);
session_start();
```